# What Is a Geometric Algebra Model For Compound Gyroscopes?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, gyroscopes, clifford-algebra

Since geometric algebra (quaternion, clifford algebra, etc.) intrinsically represents 3D rotations, I was wondering how one would model systems involving two or more gyroscopes.

For example, consider a space station that rotates to produce gravity.

[image]

In the artificial gravity, on a table sits a toy gyroscope supported at one end so that it precesses.

[image]

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19852/2451